# Why Lombok does not compile when @Wither is used?

Tags: java, lombok

I'm using Lombok 1.18.8:

```
compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'
```

Here is my simple class with `@Wither`:

```
@Wither
public class User {
    private int a;
}
```

But `withA()` method doesn't appear when I'm trying to call it in another class:

```
class test {
    User user = new User().withA(1); // withA is red
}
```

What is wrong with my code?

UPD: Other Lombok annotations work. For example `@Setter`, `@Getter`, and `@NoArgsConstructor`.

Comment: Probably you need to customize your IDE. https://projectlombok.org/setup/intellij

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Lombok 1.18.8: @Wither

If you look at the actual implementation of `withA()` you will notice that it relies on an all-args constructors. To make your example work, try to add it, as well as a no-arg constructor:

```
@Wither
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {
    private int a;
}
```

The *delombok*'d version is:

```
public class User {
    private int a;

    public User withA(int a) {
        return this.a == a ? this : new User(a);
    }

    public User(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public User() {
    }
}
```

Note: This has been tested with Lombok 1.18.8, IntelliJ IDEA and Lombok plugin.

#### Lombok 1.18.10: @With

`@With` has been promoted and `@Wither` deprecated:
Simply replace `lombok.experimental.Wither` with `lombok.With`. Everything else is similar to `1.18.8`:

```
@With
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {
    private int a;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works. But I don't understand why AllArgsConstructor required. More clearly if it was @Setter

Comment: @ValeriyK. Because `withA()` is NOT a setter. It re-creates a new User, with all values equals to this.

Comment: I understand. I think it will be better with the setter - public User withA(int a) { this.setA(a); return this; }

Comment: @ValeriyK. I believe the theory behind this feature is "*We want an object with this value*". Yes, modifying the current instance would fulfill that theory, as *any* instance of that type would be a candidate for having the value. However, with a setter, we're forced to modify an instance that may be in use elsewhere. **Using a setter introduces a side effect** that goes beyond the theory mentioned above, which was probably not wanted when designing the feature.

Comment: how did you figure out you needed the no-arg constructor? Brilliant!

Comment: @GeoffLangenderfer In Java, when you define no constructor at all, you get by default a free, no-arg constructor. But as soon as you explicitly define a constructor (in this case via the annotation `@AllArgsConstructor`), this default constructor just vanishes. Hence the annotation `@NoArgsConstructor` to get it back and make PO's code work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are just missing the installation of the `Lombok` on `intellij`
double click on `Lombok.jar` and chose the `intelliJ IDE`

Example config for lombok annotation procession in your `build.gradle` :

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.20')
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.20'
    // compile 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.20' <-- this no longer works!
    // other dependencies...
}
```

> @Wither is deprecated since 10.X.X. With has been promoted to the main
>   package, so use that one instead.

Please look at this [Lombok Wither](https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/experimental/Wither.html)

that's why you are not having the withA() function, if you downgrade your package you could use it sure

Comment: From [docs](https://projectlombok.org/features/With) : Wither was renamed to With, and moved out of experimental and into the core package, in lombok v1.18.10. But he is using 1.18.8, so I don't think your answer resolves the issue.

Comment: I think he's just missing the installation of the Lombok on intellij

Comment: No. Other Lombok annotations works. Setter, Getter for example

Comment: Are you using Maven ?

Comment: @YoussefTounoussi no gradle.

Comment: I don't know how to configure the gradle for lombok annotation processing, but it seems that @Mark Bramnik is all rights

Answer (score 0):

Line `compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'` shows that you're using gradle.

I think the easiest way to check whether it works or not can be just running the gradle build (without IDE). 
Since lombok is an annotation processor, as long as the code passes the compilation, it's supposed to work (and the chances are that it really works based on that line).

So you should check how does the IDE (you haven't specified which IDE it is actually) integrate with lombok. Maybe you need to enable "annotation processing" if you compile it with java compiler (like in intelliJ) and configure lombok. You an also install Lombok plugin for your IDE.

Another useful hint is to use delombok and see whether the lombok has actually generated something or not